# Solving this problem of convexity of $N\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let us consider the following set of $ \mathbb{C}^2$:
$$
N=\{(|a|^2-|b|^2,2\Re e(a\overline{b}));\;x =(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\;\;\hbox{and}\;|a|^2+|b|^2=1\}
$$

> I want to prove that $N$ is convex or to construct a counter-example which show that $N$ is not a convex set of $ \mathbb{C}^2$.

We see that $N\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. I try to show that $N$ is not convex:

$(1; 0),\,(-1; 0)\in N$ but their midpoint $(0; 0)\in N$.

Thank you

Comment: You have to take two elements of $N$, say, $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$, and check whether $\alpha (x,y) + (1-\alpha) (u,v)$ is also in $N$ for any $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set $N$ is simply the closed unit disk, which is convex.

If $a,b\in\mathbb C$ are such that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, then$$a=r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)\text{ and }b=\sqrt{1-r^2}(\cos\beta+i\sin\beta),$$for some $r\in[0,1]$ and some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$. Therefore $|a|^2-|b|^2=r^2-(1-r^2)=2r^2-1\in[-1,1]$. On the other hand, $2\operatorname{Re}\bigl(a\overline b\bigr)=2r\sqrt{1-r^2}\cos(\alpha-\beta)$. So, if $(x,y)\in N$, then, for some $r\in[0,1]$, $x=2r^2-1$ and $y\in\left[-2r\sqrt{1-r^2},2r\sqrt{1-r^2}\right]$. Note that$$x=2r^2-1\iff r=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}2}$$and that therefore$$y\in\left[-2r\sqrt{1-r^2},2r\sqrt{1-r^2}\right]\iff y\in\left[-\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-x^2}\right].$$So, this proves that $N$ is a subset of the closed unit disk.

On the other hand, if $(x,y)$ belongs to that disk, set $r=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}2}$. Then$$|y|\leqslant\sqrt{1-x^2}=2r\sqrt{1-r^2}.$$So, $y=2r\sqrt{1-r^2}\cos\gamma$, for some $\gamma\in\mathbb R$. So, take $a=r(\cos\gamma+i\sin\gamma)$ and $b=\sqrt{1-r^2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'm facing difficulties to show that $N=[-1,1]\times[0,1]$. What do you mean by this symbol $\wedge$?Would you please help me with helping hints. And thank you in advance.

Comment: @Student The symbol $\wedge$ means “and”. I made a mistake: it should be $[-1,1]$ insteado of $[0,1]$ (I will edit it). If $a,b\in\mathbb C$ are such that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, then $a=r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)$ and $b=\sqrt{1-r^2}(\cos\beta+i\sin\beta)$, for some $r\in[0,1]$ and some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$. But then $|a|^2-|b|^2=2r^2-1$ and this can be any number from $[-1,1]$. And $2\operatorname{Re}\bigl(a\overline b\bigr)=2r\sqrt{1-r^2}\cos(\alpha-\beta)$, and this, again, can be any number from $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I think you have only show that $N\subseteq[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. Is the converse inclusion true? Thank you very much

Comment: @Student My answer was wrong. Sorry about that. I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful.